# request for member in something not a structure or union error

Tags: c, struct

I searched the net for the above error, but people mainly talking about the wrong way of access the fields of the struct (-> vs .). I tried them, but still I keep receiving the same error. 
I have these two structs:

```
struct Node_ {
    int num;
    G12_t* G12;
}node_t;

struct G12_{
    int level;
    int size;
    G12_t* next;
}G12_t;
```

When I want to get access to the level field of G12_t in a node_t, I get the above error. I access to the level field as bellow:

```
node_t* pNode;

pNode->G12->level = 0;
```

Comment: `node_t` is not a type but a variable. You probably forgot the `typedef`. And don't invent such complicated naming conventions for types. `Node` should do just fine for the `struct` and the `typedef`: `typedef struct Node Node`. Also you'd have to have the declaration of `G12` before the one of  `Node`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you were attempting to create typedefs for these two types, but you didn't use the `typedef` keyword.  What you did instead was create an instance of `struct G12_` called `G12_t` and an instance of `struct Node_` called `node_t`.

You need to add the `typedef` keyword before each one.  Also, you need to define `G12_t` before `node_t`, since the latter uses the former, and you can use the `G12_t` name inside the struct where it's defined.  You need to use the full struct name:

```
typedef struct G12_{
    int level;
    int size;
    struct G12_* next;
}G12_t;

typedef struct Node_ {
    int num;
    G12_t* G12;
}node_t;
```

Comment: Another way would be to have the `typedefs` declarations before the `struct` definitions. `typedef struct G12 G12;`, `typedef struct Node Node;` and then the order of the `struct` definitions is free.